# How to see polygon's local axis in Animation Nodes?

Tags: animation-nodes

Sometimes it is very handy to visualize local axis to debug polygons' rotation (like 3D Viewer for location of points). Is there any default solution for this task?

This is an `Axis` type of displaying particles and I'd like to build something similiar in Animation Nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the local axis of a polygon is not exactly defined, one can generate a possible transformation for the polygon using the *Extract Polygon Transforms* node:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I want. Are colored axis only present in Blender 2.8? Mine from AN v2.1 in Blender 2.79 are simple empties

Comment: @SergeL Yes, colored axis are only in Blender 2.8.